# Invalid token after upgrading Joomla to 3.5

Tags: login, joomla-3.5, upgrade, authentication, security-token

After upgrading my site to J3.5, users can't login anymore. They get the "invalid token" error.

I tried myself around 30 times and I also get the error, although I can login to the admin area.

I cleared Joomla cache, browser cache and truncated the `#__session` table.

But the problem persists.

This is critical! Users are paying to access certain areas of my site.

WHat more do I have to do to enable user login again????

Comment: One advice: Never, never upgrade (or even update) without making a copy of your website first! Plus it is highly recommended to test the upgrade on a copy of the website before doing it on the production website!

Comment: @ Philippe: two years after your reply: thank! This finally worked for me after scanning many other discussions! Turning off the system cache didn't work. But adding the login-menu-item to the System Page Cache plugin helped.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there area couple of issues with Joomla **3.5.0**, one being to do with the session.

Joomla **3.5.1** will be released tonight, hopefully fixing your issue.

---

It may be an idea to put your site offline for a couple of hours until the update is released. And in future, I'd recommend taking a backup of your site and testing Joomla updates locally before applying them to your live site

Comment: Ok, I always trusted Joomla team had done extensive testing before going live with a new version but at least it's good to know the issue has been addressed. Thank you

Comment: @NunoNogueira - Extensive testing is always done. 2 tests are required for small PR's (but usually more are done). Joomla 3.5 had 5 betas and 4 RC's. Some things can get missed though, just the way it is unfortunately ;)

Comment: BTW @Lodder - How do you know that J3.5.1 will be released tonight? I thought I am following on Twitter everybody-Joomla under the Sun, but I haven't heard that rumour... :/

Comment: @Mikan - Cause I know people :)

Comment: <envy>echo "cool"; </envy>

Comment: Try this fix https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/943f2e9197a412bf7295bb50ff94988e855c8805 and if it doesn't work then Lodder is wrong about tonight's release helping you :P

Comment: https://twitter.com/GW1992/status/712274101293998082 lodder's contact just gave the game away on twitter i feel ;)

Comment: @GeorgeWilson thanks, is that fix replacing core joomla files?

Comment: @NunoNogueira Yes, it's a core file located here: `ROOT/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php`. Please check the comments in the commit though

Comment: Yah turns out that fix was a baaad idea :( serves me right for trying to code before I had my first coffee of the morning!

Comment: @Lodder there was no new release of J3.5.1. I still get the error "invalid token"

Comment: @NunoNogueira - Are you using any 3rd party extensions for user management, such as Community Builder?

Comment: @Lodder No, I'm using core Joomla login/register.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - and do you have a backup of your Joomla 3.4 site from before the upgrade? Is it all the users (including yourself) that are unable to login?

Comment: @Lodder Yes, I have a backup before the upgrade, but in the meantime new users/orders/posts/tickets have been issued. Therefore, it's too painful to go back. BTW there are other users complaining, as you can see here:http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=913811&p=3380467#p3380467

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the System - Page Cache
The issue is related to the cache.

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix the problem. But the cache is necessary so I still need a permanent solution.

Comment: I found that as soon as I login, "page" is in the cache. I clean the cache I can login back. It has to do with that but I haven't had time to dig deeper to see what's wrong. For now, no cache does it... waiting for a permanent solution too...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the cookie domain and cookie path, erase the content so that it looks like this:

> public $cookie_domain = '';
>    public $cookie_path = '';

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Install PCE - Page Cache Extended Plugin from [this page](https://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/pce-page-cache-extended)
2. Disable core Joomla cache and replace it by this plugin instead
3. In the plugin configs, exclude components: `com_users`
4. Use core Joomla component to register/login users. No `mod_login` no 3rd party extensions

**PS:** Joomla should allow disabling cache to whatever components/modules necessary. I can see it is already possible to exclude URLs but what if you have a module `mod_login` in main the main menu or a custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I solved it in 2 simple steps:

1. In Joomla! go to plugins / System - Page Cache
2. In the plugin there is an option to exclude menu items. I excluded the menu item where the login form was located.

That's it. Now it works on my site. I can login, logout repeatedly and never get the invalid token error.
NOTE: On logout, my users are redirected to the same page where they logged in (the one I excluded from system - page cache). I don't know if it plays a role or not.

Hope it helps.